# Excel : Extract text before space in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, syntax-error, excel-2010

The formula that I worte used to work on my other laptop so I'm seriouly wondering if the problem comes from the formula itself. I put `A B` in cell A1 and `=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1)` in cell B1. Both cells' number format is general. Here is the error message:

[image: Here is the error message]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to replace the commas in your Excel formula by semi-colons.

Comment: I have tried your formula in latest Excel version and it works fine.

Comment: @Dominique I tried and =LEFT(A1;(FIND(" ";A1,1)-1)) doesn't work either...

Comment: When you type `=LEFT(` in an empty cell, you should get a hint on how to continue, what does this hint look like? In case you don't get a hint, then maybe you are working with a non-English version.

Comment: Works fine on Office 365 as well

Comment: I typed `=LEFT(` and saw that I should use semi-colon as separators. I rebooted Excel and this time it worked. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Excel and used semi-colon.